# How to get the average rating for on before some day and after some days in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I need to get the average rating for a video, for this video there is the field called release date, so i need to get rating for the on before release date and after release date,

now i have the query to get only the rating on before video release date as follows

```
select d.mth Month,
  coalesce(avg(t.rating), 0) Rating
from 
(
  select 1 mth union all
  select 2 mth union all
  select 3 mth union all
  select 4 mth union all
  select 5 mth union all
  select 6 mth union all
  select 7 mth union all
  select 8 mth union all
  select 9 mth union all
  select 10 mth union all
  select 11 mth union all
  select 12 mth 
) d
left join wp_fatalcut_videos_rating t
  on d.mth = month(t.ratingdate)
where d.mth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) and videoid='3192763' and ratingdate <=  '2013-10-09 00:00:00'
group by d.mth
```

i need to get the rating for the after video release that is after '2013-10-09 00:00:00' in same Query, is this is possible ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just do this? If I understand you correct:

```
select d.mth Month,
  coalesce(avg(t.rating), 0) Rating,
  coalesce(avg(tafter.rating), 0) RatingAfter
from 
(
  select 1 mth union all
  select 2 mth union all
  select 3 mth union all
  select 4 mth union all
  select 5 mth union all
  select 6 mth union all
  select 7 mth union all
  select 8 mth union all
  select 9 mth union all
  select 10 mth union all
  select 11 mth union all
  select 12 mth 
) d
left join wp_fatalcut_videos_rating t
  on d.mth = month(t.ratingdate) 
  AND t.videoid='3192763' and t.ratingdate <=  '2013-10-09 00:00:00'
left join wp_fatalcut_videos_rating tafter
  on d.mth = month(tafter.ratingdate) 
  AND tafter.videoid='3192763' and tafter.ratingdate >=  '2013-10-09 00:00:00'
where d.mth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
group by d.mth
```

I think that this were statement is unnecessary

```
where d.mth in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

Becuse you will not have month in the table `mth` which is for example 0,13, or 14. Right?

Comment: it cause this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=> '2013-10-09 00:00:00' group by d.mth' at line 24

Comment: Updated query working without error, but it doesn't return the rating values, in previous it does

Comment: Did another update. It is strange that the queries do not return the same values as the first. Because the column rating should be the same as it was before.